# Validation by PCR of a lowly expressed gene in microarray

Tags: gene-expression, pcr, microarray

I am interested in validating the precence of a gene (FETUB) whose expression is in the lower quartile of the microarray (see figure in link).

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B82aQne0d_mYWlFiMjRlb05CUVU

Do you think this gene would be detectable by PCR?

Thanks

Comment: If your lab is lacking specific expertise on qPCR, and you need a sensitive and quantitative readout of transcripts, branched DNA single-molecule FISH may be less work than PCR ( while also being more sensitive and quantitative than RNAseq etc. )

Answer (score 1):

If it was detectable in a microarray, the odds are very good for RT-rtPCR. If you are designing your own primers, make sure they span an exon junction, or if the gene is intronless, then span the UTR to exon junction to avoid amplifying DNA.